# Syntax error on owasp rules

Tags: apache, syntax, mod-security

**EDITED: My last move was remove spaces and some other modifications. still no results**

I created a whitelist.conf for the modsecurity-crs rules.

I put that simple code

`<LocationMatch "/">
</LocationMatch>`

The result is

> httpd: Syntax error on line 420 of /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 14 of /usr/local/apache/conf.d/mod_security.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /usr/local/apache/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/whitelist.conf: /usr/local/apache/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/whitelist.conf:1:  was not closed.
>                                                              [FAILED]

How can it be a syntax error?
Im really stucked with that.

Note: If i put an empty fail, do not fai and obviosly does nothing.
If a put `</LocationMatch>` the fail is about not detect `<LocationMatch>` opening tag.

Seems to do not recognize `</LocationMatch>` at all.
Examples here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/disable-mod-security

**UPDATED:**
I really think that the bundled (in some hosting package i won't mention) CSR did contain some mistake, because i used it without modify it at all, so, something is wrong from the start. After reading nothing made it work, so i've simply leaved that hosting software provinding that. I'll not expect that weird behavior for a up-to-date CSR with not custom tweaking. Thanks.

Comment: what context is whitelist.conf included from?

Comment: the file `/usr/local/apache/conf.d/mod_security.conf` load all files on the directory `/usr/local/apache/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/`.

I just created a new rule and i get error. I've tried with "empty" value and still get that. If you leave the file really empty, does not fail.

My goal is just to put an ID under whitelist to allow wordpress work with mod_sec.

You can watch an example right here https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-disable-modsecurity-rules-drupal-and-wordpress

Comment: Really a strange problem. I've setup a local ModSecurity (2.9.0) from scratch, included the OWASP base rules and added a whitelist.conf which includes the `LocationMatch` exclusion rule as described in the blogpost you posted and it works without any problems. Could you also post the failing configuration lines from httpd.conf and mod_security.conf. Does the folder `activated_rules` also include all other OWASP rules from the `base_rules` directory and did you include the `modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf` file in the `activated_rules` directory?

Comment: @derhansen I've traced all the files, checking the calls and include directories. It works and blocks my main website and also i know wich rules is blocking. My problem comes when i try to disallow it. My owasp is also from scratch, i've not modify ANYTHING. Seems the file is not parsing right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you have to find which rule blocked your script .

You can find the errors and rule Id's on the file "modsec_audit.log"

All requests that trigger a ModSecurity events (as detected) or a serer error are logged ("RelevantOnly") are logged into this file.

This file must be located on /usr/local/apache/logs/modsec_audit.log or /var/log/httpd/modsec_audit.log

Open file : /usr/local/apache/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/whitelist.conf

So , you can disable the rule for that file or files with this code :

```
<LocationMatch "/patchtofile">
    SecRuleRemoveById 000000
</LocationMatch>
```

You have to replace patchtofile > file you got error on modsec_audit.log , and you need to replace 000000 with the  rule ID you finded on log file . you have to this for each file and error you found.

Also you can disable the rules for a whole directory you want :

```
<LocationMatch "/patchtodir">
    SecRuleRemoveById 000000
</LocationMatch>
```

Replace patchtodir with directory patch and replace the rule Id too

Comment: I've understand how it works. I've tried it with a EMPY LocationMatch and the result is `activated_rules/whitelist.conf:1: was not closed`

If i do not put content on whitelist.conf no problem comes up.

Comment: why you tried empty LocationMatch ? you have to say it , what to do .  it can't work without set the right configuration ! you have to use an option in locationmatch tag before close it ! like SecRuleRemoveById

Comment: Im sure our first problem is my BAD english. I have SAY. First i tried THE NORMAL WAY, using the id of the desired rule to disable it. Result? a big fail. Because i don't believe on magic powers, i digg into the problem the finally end up with the example i post. I got parse problem, when you can CLEARLY SEE THE TAG IS CLOSED. This is my question.

Comment: you have to use an option in locationmatch tag before close it ! 
This affirmation seems false. As i say, i've tried why real/dummy/modified rules and the result is ALWAYS the same. Didn't recognize the close tag. Thank you for your time, always.

Comment: Nope dear , so please send the Big Error/Fail you said when using the SecRuleRemoveById in locationmatch ? also , can you send last 100 line of modsec_audit.log and httpd Error log too ?

Comment: Im sorry about last comment, i was posted a false positive. Still not work. I'll publish the log.

Comment: Okay , NO problem , send the log when you can and i will tell you where is the issue

Comment: Im so sorry, i've rebuild the machine. I will try to enable it again, im pretty sure the problem will come up again, and i will send the log in that case. Best regards.

Comment: Okay , I hope you will rebuild successfull without any problem , but if you see any problem . let me know

Comment: i've leaved that shi* of software then moved to another, but understanding that your theory is right (the same i followed when configuring) i've marked as righ, but indeed my problem didn't solved :). Sorry about forgot to mark, im not confidend with asking on there, as never did get a successfull answer for my custom problems :-)  thank you.